# Use of "Look on" instead of "Look at"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, archaicisms

In the film *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* there's a line:

> Just for once, let me **look on** you with my own eyes.

According to Oxford Dictionaries Online, it means:

> Watch without getting involved: *Cameron was looking on and making no move to help*

But the above definition doesn't seem to fit in the context. Many people tell me that it's just poetic, emphatic and emotional version of "**look at**".

Is that true?

Comment: You might want to include a [bit of research](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/look_on) which proves that at least one dictionary is no help at all. But have you looked elsewhere?

Comment: "Look on" does have a non-archaic meaning, as in "The medic administered first aid while several bystanders *looked on*."  But in the above it's simply a poetic/archaic version of "look at".

Comment: Hi, SovereignSun. Don't forget to include your research when you ask a question. I think the downvote was cast because of that. I edited your question and please take a look. You don't need to use **bold** for so many words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an archaic usage that is being used poetically in this case. The King James Version of the Bible uses *look on* instead of *look at*:

> And it came to pass in those days, when Moses was grown, that he went out unto his brethren, and **looked on** their burdens: and he spied an Egyptian smiting an Hebrew, one of his brethren.

Exodus 2:11 (KJV)

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+on%2Clook+at&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20at%3B%2Cc0) shows the relative usage of "look on" and "look at":

[image]

Google Books Ngram Viewer